# FN key to program X keys

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem. I have a MacBook Pro and a Xkeys 80. Xkeys basically records shortcut keys like a macro. But it is not sensing the push of the FN key. I use a program called controller mate to program the Xkeys and they are of no real help on the issue. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas how to go about putting the FN key on a different key or the unicode so that I can get the Xkeys to grab it as a key press. I know this sounds weird and I understand in my head what I am saying just not how to describe it. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't help, but you could try using a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::FN</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).